# rawquery elastic search query in nest - fields not populated

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This works fine:

```
var rawQuery = @"
    {
        ""query_string"": {
             ""query"": ""hello world""
             ,""default_operator"": ""AND""
        }
    }
";

var searchResponse = client.Search<Doc>(new SearchRequest
{
    Query = new RawQuery(rawQuery), Size = 1000
});
```

Unfortunately, no field of the POCO Doc is populated apart from the Id. Any ideas why this is?

PS:

More (simplified) details as requested

```
public class Doc
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}

public static void CreateIndex(ElasticClient client, string indexName)
{
    var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create(indexName, c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
        .Analyzers(ad => ad
            .Custom("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer", ca => ca
            .Tokenizer("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer")
            )
        )
        .Tokenizers(t => t
            .PathHierarchy("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer", ph => ph
            .Delimiter('\\')
            )
        )
        )
    )
    .Map<Doc>(mp => mp
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(ps => ps
        .Text(s => s
            .Name(n => n.Id)
            .Analyzer("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer")
        )
        .Object<Attachment>(a => a
            .Name(n => n.Attachment)
            .AutoMap()
        )
        )
    )
    );

    var putPipelineResponse = client.Ingest.PutPipeline("attachments", p => p
    .Description("Document attachment pipeline")
    .Processors(pr => pr
        .Attachment<Doc>(a => a
        .Field(f => f.Content)
        .TargetField(f => f.Attachment)
        )
        .Remove<Doc>(r => r
        .Field(ff => ff
            .Field(f => f.Content)
        )
        )
    )
    );
}
```

PPS:

So I used:

```
http:/SomeWhere:9200/amazingindex/_search?pretty=true
```

and the fields are called, for example, fileName fileExtension. So I created a POCO using these names/capitalization. Still the fields are not populated apart from the Id and the Nest Attachment. I guess I have to move away from NEST to send raw queries and populate POCOs.

Comment: can you provide your index mapping, sample docs

Comment: thanks. see ps: hth?

Comment: sorry i hvn't worked with c#, can you provide this in JSON format, you can hit `_mapping` API of elastic to get it

Comment: sorry that would be massive and would reveal too much confidential info ...

Comment: yeah I can understand, so can you create a minimum reproducible example, which we can use to guide you?

Comment: Is there a casing difference between what is stored in Elasticsearch, and what case the client expects (camel case fields by default)?

Comment: @RussCam - see PPS - just updated my question.

Comment: Can you provide the index mapping?

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance but how do I obtain it?

Comment: Make a HTTP GET request to path `/amazingindex/_mapping`, the Get Mapping API:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html